# Missing required parameter for [Route: admin.editproduct] [URI: admin/product/edit/{product_slug}] [Missing parameter: product_slug]

Tags: php, database, laravel

This is the error :
Missing required parameter for [Route: admin.editproduct] [URI: admin/product/edit/{product_slug}] [Missing parameter: product_slug]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\livewire\admin\admin-product-component.blade.php)

This is my web.php :

```
 Route::get('/admin/product/edit/{product_slug}',AdminEditProductComponent::class)->name('admin.editproduct');
```

In my admin-product-component.blade.php I added this:

```
 <div>
    <div class="admin"  style="padding: 30px 0;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                                  <div class="row">
                                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                              <a href="{{route('admin.addproduct')}}" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add New</a>
                                          </div>

                                  </div>
                          </div>
                               <div class="panel-body">

<table class="table">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
       <tr>
           <th class="table">Id</th>
           <th class="table">image</th>
           <th class="table">Name</th>
           <th class="table">Price</th>
           <th class="table ">Category</th>
           <th class="table ">Date</th>
           <th class="table ">Action</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
</tbody>
  @foreach ($products as $product)
          <tr>
                 <td>{{$product->id}}</td>
                 <td><img src="{{asset('storage/imagg')}}/{{$product->image}}" width="60"></td>
                 <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
                 <td>{{$product->regular_price}}</td>
                 <td>{{$product->category->name}}</td>
                 <td>{{$product->created_at}}</td>
                 <td>
                 <a href="{{route('admin.editproduct',['product_slug'=>$product->slug])}}"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x text-info"></i></a>
                 </td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{$products->links()}}
</div>
```

And finally the AdminEditProductComponent :

```
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
class AdminEditProductComponent extends Component
{
   use WithFileUploads;
    public $name;
   public $slug;
   public $short_description;
   public $description;
   public $regular_price;
   public $sale_price;
   public $featured;
   public $quantity;
   public $stock_status;
   public $SKU;
   public $image;
   public $category_id;
   public $newimage;
   public $product_id;
   public function mount($product_slug)
   {
       $product = Product::where('slug',$product_slug)->first();
       $this->$name = $product->name;
       $this->$slug = $product->slug;
       $this->$short_description = $product->short_description;
       $this->$description =  $product->description ;
       $this->$regular_price =  $product->regular_price;
       $this->$sale_price =  $product->sale_price;
       $this->$featured =  $product->featured;
       $this->$quantity =  $product->quantity;
       $this->$stock_status =  $product->stock_status;
       $this->$SKU =  $product->SKU;
       $this->$image =  $product->image;
       $this->$category_id =  $product->category_id;
       $this->$product_id =  $product->product_id;
   }
   public function generateSlug()
   {
       $this->slug = Str::slug($this->name, '-');
   }
   public function updateProduct()
   {
       $product = Product::find($this->product_id);
       $product->name = $this->name;
       $product->slug = $this->slug;
       $product->short_description = $this->short_description;
       $product->description = $this->description;
       $product->regular_price = $this->regular_price;
       $product->sale_price = $this->sale_price;
       $product->featured = $this->featured;
       $product->SKU = $this->SKU;
       $product->stock_status = $this->stock_status;
       $product->quantity = $this->quantity;
       if($this->newimage)
       {
           $imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp.'.'. $this->newimage->extension();
           $this->newimage->storeAs('imagg',$imageName,'public');
           $product->image = $imageName;
       }

       $product->category_id = $this->category_id;
       $product->save();
       session()->flash('message', 'Product has been updated successfully !');
   }
   public function render()
   {
       $category = Category::all();
       return view('livewire.admin.admin-edit-product-component',['categories'=>$categories])->layout('layouts.admin-category');
   }
}
```

Comment: Show you complate `admin-product-component.blade.php`

Comment: Try `dd($product)` check it has slug value or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it optional by putting `?`

```
Route::get('/admin/product/edit/{product_slug?}',AdminEditProductComponent::class)->name('admin.editproduct');
```

Answer (score -1):

You have set key parameter right now you're using slug but laravel is using id to find the model but you're passing slug
There are two ways
Define the key in your route like this

```
 Route::get('/admin/product/edit/{product:slug}',AdminEditProductComponent::class)->name('admin.editproduct');
```

or define it in your model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```